# How to download Egyptian Arabic articles from Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, wiki, wikipedia-api

I am a researcher and I need to download many ( or all) the Egyptian dialect pages in Wikipedia?

I am totally new to this. any help please

Comment: I found this but this is for English and standard languages like Arabic but not specific Egyptian Arabic

Comment: Egyptian Arabic was not included in Wikipedia since 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the Wikipedia Database Dumps. The information about this dumps are reported in the [Database Dumps Page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download), and an HTML version of the site is usually available in the [HTML static Dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/static_html_dumps/current/).

As you correctly pointed out, the Egyptian Arabic (`arz` in ISO 639-3) language is not available in the Static HTML repository, but the database is available at the [following official mirror](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/wikimedia.org/dumps/arzwiki/) (as reported in Database Dump Page) as SQL database. The schema for the database should be compatible with the common Wikipedia schema, which is [described here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout).

I suggest you to carefully [read this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Other_languages), which provides additional information about the initialization of the database itself for local use and also suggests **to never user web crawlers on the public Wikipedia sites**. The same pages contains some script to parse and query the database.

There is an alternative. You may try to use resources such as [dbpedia.org](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/), which declares some dumps for `arz` language and can be queried with sql queries directly.

Happy Download!